# Waypoints hijacking e.clientY

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-waypoints

I have jQuery waypoints enabled in my project, which simply fade in each section of the page as you scroll.

Additionally, I have a single section of the page that has a `position: fixed;` div inside of it that follows the cursor.

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  dragIcon.el.css({left: e.clientX, top: clientY});
});
```

What ends up happening is on a waypoint triggered module is that the Y-pos gets highjacked and whenever you scroll, the `top` css val does not update (on the cursor trail div).

Disabling this class / turning off waypoints entirely fixes this issue.

`Waypoint.destroy()` does not seem to have any affect ([per Wapoint docs](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/destroy/))

Thoughts?

Comment: Is there any additional code you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by simply moving the dragIcon.el out of the waypoints activated div. Children elements of those are apparently scroll jacked on the Y-axis.